# Return values based on multiple criteria (index and match formula)

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, google-sheets-formula, criteria

I have a pivot table that identifies the number of reviews completed by person and quarter. We can only payout for the first 2 reviews and it must be billed during the appropriate quarter. I am struggling with the formula to identify the second review quarter. This is the formula I used to identify the first quarter: =IFERROR(index($C$1:$F$1,match(FALSE,isblank($C2:$F2),0)),"")

I am trying to modify it so that it will return the quarter the second review was done so for example paper 4 would be Q2 for the initial review quarter and Q4 for the second review while Paper 6 would be Q2 for the initial review quarter and second review quarter.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jh9WwlxJqnrXfOkwuYUgsBJuYIJtBvMkqSp52_Har2A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a link to your sample spreadsheet. As it stands, there are not even any ranges shown around which to write any potential formulas. I also suggest that you *hand-enter* the results you would like to see a formula return, as that is not clear in your post (e.g., why is "Initial Review QTR" for Paper 2 / Person 2 listed as "Q3"?).

Comment: Please share the sample sheet. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior and the actual behavior, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Apologies, I was short on time and forgot to include the column headers and rows. I updated the post to include a sample sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample sheet you shared and taking in consideration that you only need Qtr for 1st and 2nd review, I added a column (you can hide this column if you prefer) between “Initial Qtr Review” and “Second Review Qtr” with the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(index($C2:$F2,match(FALSE,isblank($C2:$F2),0)),"")
```

[image]

This returns how many reviews were done in the quarter shown in the “Initial Qtr Review” column.

In the “Second Review Qtr” column, I added this formula:

```
=IF(H2>1, G2, IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER($C$1:$F$1,C2:F2<>""),2),""))
```

[image]

If there is more than one review in the “Initial Qtr Review” column, then it means that the 2nd review was done in the same quarter, otherwise it returns the index of the second review.

This is the result for the sample sheet you shared:
[image]

If you have any doubts let me know.